# Extract v flavoring

Tags: flavor

What is the difference in measurements when using flavoring vs. extract? I.e.: orange flavoring vs. orange extract. I've used the extract but there is an alcohol taste that I don't want.

Comment: How are you using the extract? It does taste like alcohol if you just taste it, but when it's part of a dish, it should definitely be the orange flavor that comes through.

Comment: I'm using it to flavor a cheesecake (Orange Creme).  It tastes just like a Creamsicle but there is definitely an alcohol taste.

Answer (score 3):

Orange **extract** is - as this term says - an extract of oranges. The aroma of oranges is often extracted at first as an oil. To make this extract soluble to water, the aroma is extracted to ethanol (alcohol) and may be diluted with water. Extracts should be used sparingly because the aroma is concentrated. (Pure) Extracts may have a relatively short shelf life since they are made from natural ingredients.

Hoever, the term orange **flavoring** does neither say from where the flavor comes from nor says something about the relative concentration. The flavor can be from real oranges (which is unlikely, otherwise it would be called "extract") or other natural sources (e.g. from a culture of fungi) or can be artifical. Flavoring comes in liquid (as an oily or alcohol-containing "extract" like this:

[image]

) or dry form ([as grains or flakes](http://thegermanshop.com.au/Shop/images/NeuDrOetkerFinesseOrangenschalenaroma.JPG)). Flavorings can have longer shelf life because the artificial flavoring might be more stable and other (artificial) preservatives might be allowed. Oh, and (artificial) flavoring is likely much cheaper.

In your case - if you don't intend to flavor beverages or very watery food - I would use orange oil or flavoring "flakes". If you want to flavor beverages, I think you must use these flavoring "flakes" if you want to avoid alcohol.